# how to send event to chrome extension from C# native host

Tags: c#, .net-core, google-chrome-extension, named-pipes, chrome-native-messaging

I had created a chrome extension and a c# host application, the chrome app is sending events to the c# host application. But how we can receive the events in chrome from the host app.

Comment: Currently extensions must initiate the messaging cycle. Your extension should send a message then your host app can answer it when it wants - the extension should be able to wait indefinitely, AFAIK.

Comment: The feature you want seems to be implemented only in Chrome dev-channel, see https://crbug.com/967262.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this; a C# application can control the Chrome add-on using the native messaging and the pipe channel.

The pipe stream channel is connected between two C# apps and one end of the pipe is connected to the native messaging which is a channel for the browser and the C# app.

But my application is not completely ready. I'm working on it to get a reliable channel communication between these two channels.